# How to append items of a list to another list using a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

Having two lists:

```
list1 = ['Me','You','Sam']
list2 = ['Joe','Jen']
```

How can I append items of `list2` to the `list1`?
Expected result is:

```
['Me', 'You','Sam','Joe','Jen']
```

My failed attempt:

```
list1 = ("Bobs","Sams","Jacks"); 
foreach list2 in list1:
    list3 = list2 + " list item"

print list3
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Why don't you start with the obvious : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: The code you say you tried would not compile, and if it did, it would not produce output containing the word "array".

Comment: sorry `Jacks array item` was the output

Comment: `list1` is **not** a list. Is a  `tuple` (which is immutable, by the way). Use square brackets to have a list: `[1,2,3]`. Then try to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) in particular [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
list1 = ['Me','You','Sam']
list2 = ['Joe','Jen']

for item in list2:
   list1.append(item)
```

list1 now is `['Me', 'You','Sam','Joe','Jen']`

If you want a third list, simply define it and append to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things are wrong with your code.

**First**:

`list = ("Bobs", "Sams", "Jacks");` should be `list = ["Bobs", "Sams", "Jacks"]`

**Second**:

```
foreach list2 in list1:
    list3 = list2 + " list item"
```

should be

```
list3 = []
for item in list1:
   list3.append(item)
```

Comment: Their `for` loop would be more like `for item in list1: print('{} list item'.format(item))`