# How to turn the output of a while loop (or a for loop) into a list (or a dictionary) in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, output

## A loop to reverse a number

```
def is_reverse(number):

    reverse = 0
    while number > 0:

        remainder = number % 10
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder
        number = number // 10
    #print(reverse)
    return reverse
```

## A function to get a set of ages that fulfill the conditions

## on the exercise 9.9 of Think Python book

```
def ages():

    number = 12
    while number < 100:

        x = number - is_reverse(number)
        if number > is_reverse(number) and 20 > x > 12:

            print(number)
            #break
        number = number + 1

ages()
```

Comment: ... build a list or dictionary in the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a list using a loop python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381991/how-to-build-a-list-using-a-loop-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a list, append the results and return that list

```
def is_reverse(number):
    reverse = 0
    while number > 0:

        remainder = number % 10
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder
        number = number // 10
    #print(reverse)
    return reverse


def ages():

    number = 12
    li = [] 
    while number < 100:

        x = number - is_reverse(number)
        if number > is_reverse(number) and 20 > x > 12:

            li.append(number)
            #break
        number = number + 1
    return li
print ages()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I understand my mistake now. I was trying to create a list inside the while loop and I got a series of lists, one for each output.

Comment: Done.
I'm new here. How do I edit the question to add [solved]?

Comment: Its not necessary, but if you insist, just above the comment section for your question you can see edit option.